# Responsive web design: div width + padding not going across containing div even though they equal 100%

Tags: css, width, padding, responsive-design

I've got two divs, both with the following css:

```
#div-id {
width:96%;
padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
}
```

Now, I expect these divs to span the entire containing div, and they do in Firefox, but they only go around 99% of the way across in webkit browsers (haven't tested in IE yet).

Is there something specific I have to do to make them span 100% across the space in webkit browsers?

Here's what I'm working with (overtop of the McDouble burger) at [bueddefeld.com/blog](http://bueddefeld.com/blog).

Comment: In IE8 it doesn't even work. I get the `<h1>` at the the top of the image overlapping the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug in webkit browsers](http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/). That's why it's recommended you use ems instead of percentages when creating a responsive layout. [Here's the original article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) with the recommended technique to get a truly responsive layout working across all modern browsers.